# Get all INACTIVE processes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to list all *inactive* process names of applications in PowerShell?

To get the active process names I use:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Name
```

Also, by inactive, I mean process names of applications that are not running. For instance, obtaining the process of a completely closed application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "inactive"? Are you hoping to enumerate _suspended_ processes? Or are you hoping to obtain information about the System Idle Process?

Comment: By inactive, I mean processes that are not running. For instance, obtaining the process of a completely closed application.

Comment: Once a process exits, the OS eventually purges all its handles and the PID - so after a short while it simply wont _exist_ on the machine any more. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps you'll want to [turn on auditing of process termination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-process-termination)?

Comment: I'm creating an application which will monitor and terminate specific applications. Stop process uses the process ID. I have tried displaying all possible applications to monitor, except I have no clue how to get the process id of those specific application to subsequently terminate them..

Comment: We may not be aligned on what inactive means. If inactive means completely closed, to many of us (myself included), that means those processes are terminated, and terminating a process ID that's already terminated wouldn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Is this still possible with process names?

Comment: @Youmahmy if a *process* isn't running, then it is obviously no longer a process... It just becomes an *executable* or a command.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally *no* information about processes unless they are *running* (except very briefly after a given process terminates and via process-information objects obtained with `Get-Process` *before* a given process terminates).

However, any *executable file* is a *potential* process; that is, invoking an executable creates a process by that name.

Therefore, a way to get an - incomplete - list of *candidate* process names would be to run [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) as follows:

```sh
# Note: Incomplete.
#       On Unix, omit the `-match` operation.
$potentialProcessNames = (Get-Command -Type Application).Name -match '\.(exe|com)$'
```

This is *incomplete* for several reasons:

- It only finds executables that can be located via the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable, i.e. those executables that can be called by *name only*.
- In other words: There can be executables located outside these directories, which can still be invoked by their *path*.
- Finding those would not only be very time-consuming, because it would require searching all available drives in full, it would still be incomplete, as it is possible to invoke executables via *UNC* paths rather than via mapped drives.